# Generics : Specify that parameter must be an interface

Tags: java, generics

I try to do a generic class like this :

```
public abstract class MyClass<A extends MyInterface,B,C> implements A{
...
}
```

(Note: B and C are not interfaces, just other generic params)

I get a compilation error because there is absolutely no guarantee that `A` is an interface. Hence, the abstract class cannot `implements A`

Is there a way to tell the compiler that A must be an interface?

Comment: No. How would you implement the interface if you cannot know which methods are in there?

Comment: Note: if you want your generic type to extend more than one class/type you have to use `&`: `A extends B & C`

Comment: @Heuster : this is an abstract class, those methods must be implemented by subclasses.

Comment: It might not be clear in this example but B and C are not interfaces. They are just other generic parameters

Comment: @adenoyelle That's good to know - I would add that directly into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,
Since you are using clause which after compilation will have following form like:

`public abstract class MyClass implements java.lang.Object {`

You can add `implements MyInterface, B, C` since that would check whether these interfaces are implemented.